# Count string matches in file since last check

Tags: powershell, logging, comparison

I am trying to make a log file monitor. I have a PowerShell command that gives me the count of the error I am looking for.

How can I now store that number, get the count again 5 minutes later and report on the difference?

Here is my code:

```
(Get-Content "file.log" | Select-String -Pattern "HandleProcessingError" -AllMatches).count
```

Comment: Store the result of .count in a variable and compare that with the one from 5 minutes later.

Comment: Or write the number to a file, the registry or an eventlog and read it back the next time your code runs

Comment: so something like this?
`$count1 = (Get-Content "file.log" | Select-String -Pattern "HandleProcessingError" -AllMatches).count`
how do I get it to stay for X minutes to compare too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one very simplistic way, but its far from ideal:

```
$ErrorCount = (Get-Content "file.log" | Select-String -Pattern "HandleProcessingError" -AllMatches).count
Start-Sleep -Seconds (60*5)

$NewErrorCount = (Get-Content "file.log" | Select-String -Pattern "HandleProcessingError" -AllMatches).count

$ErrorDifference = $NewErrorCount - $ErrorCount

Write-Output "There have been $ErrorDifference new errors"
```

What you'd be better off doing would be to write the count to a file and then set this script to run every 5 minutes as some sort of task:

```
$ErrorCountFile = 'ErrorCount.XML'
$ErrorCount = (Get-Content "file.log" | Select-String -Pattern "HandleProcessingError" -AllMatches).count

If (Test-Path $ErrorCountFile) {
    $PrevErrorCount = Import-Clixml -Path $ErrorCountFile
    $ErrorDifference = $ErrorCount - $PrevErrorCount

    Write-Output "There have been $ErrorDifference new errors"
}
$ErrorCount | Export-Clixml -Path $ErrorCountFile -Force
```

Comment: `$PrevErrorCount | Import-CliXml` -> `$PrevErrorCount = Import-CliXml`

Comment: I agree with you in storing to a file. This is what I get with that code:
`Import-Clixml : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Files\New'.
At line:4 char:36
+     $PrevErrorCount | Import-Clixml <<<<  -Path C:\Program Files\New Relic\plugins\logmonitor\ErrorCount.XML
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Import-Clixml], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportClixmlCommand`

Comment: You should update the file `ErrorCount.xml` not only in the else clause.

Comment: @LotPings I have now made that change. Thanks for pointing it out!